# Firebase Database - Check for Existing User

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I dummy users added to my Firebase DB and for testing purposes I am trying to see if I can check for a user in the DB.

I first wrote the `createUserToDatabase()` method which works perfectly. For existence querying purposes, I wrote the `doesUserExist()` method but after running it multiple times, no `snapshot` is returned. The method is called but the actual Firebase query is not performed.

Then I decided to make a simple query for all the data, hence `test()`. To my surprise, this also doesn't work even though I have used this similar querying approach on another app and it works just fine. None of the three approaches in `test()` print anything.

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseDatabase

struct FirebaseNode
{
    static let USERS: String = "Users"
}

class MainViewVC: UIViewController
{
static var userName: String?
var databaseRootRef: FIRDatabaseReference!
let currentUser: User = User.sharedInstance

@IBOutlet weak var userNameLabel: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()

    databaseRootRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

    if let userTitle = MainViewVC.userName
    {
        userNameLabel.text = userTitle
    }
    else
    {
        userNameLabel.text = ""
    }
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning()
{
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

@IBAction func createButtonAction(sender: UIButton)
{
    test()
}

func doesUserExist()
{
    databaseRootRef.child(FirebaseNode.USERS).queryEqualToValue(currentUser.uid).observeSingleEventOfType(.Value) { (snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot) in
        if snapshot.exists()
        {
            print("User exists")
        }
        else
        {
            print("User doesn't exist")
        }
    }
}

func test()
{
    databaseRootRef.observeSingleEventOfType(FIRDataEventType.ChildAdded) { (snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot) in
        print(snapshot)
    }

    databaseRootRef.observeEventType(.ChildAdded) { (snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot) in
        print(snapshot)
    }

    databaseRootRef.observeSingleEventOfType(.Value) { (snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot) in

        print(snapshot)
    }
}

func createUserToDatabase()
{
    databaseRootRef.child(FirebaseNode.USERS).child(self.currentUser.uid).setValue(self.currentUser.toAnyObject())
}
}
```

This is the structure of my Firebase DB

```
{
 "Users":
 {
     "JglJnGDXcqLq6m844pZ": ---> $uid
    {
      "userName":"Hello John",
      "firstName": "Johnita",
      "lastName":"Hernandez",
      "email":"help@mail.fabolous",
      "profileImage": "%uid%.jpeg",
    }
  }
}
```

And this is my current set of rules

```
{
  "rules": {
    "Users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid",
        ".validate": "newData.hasChildren(['email', 'firstName', 'lastName', 'userName'])"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

No error is thrown whatsoever or any reported auth problems.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I set `FIRDatabase.setLoggingEnabled(true)` inside `viewDidLoad` which helped log all the occurring events as the query was made. At the end of it, the database returned the following JSON

```
[FirebaseDatabase] Got data message: {
    b =     {
        d = "Permission denied"; |-----> Root of ALL EVIL :)
        s = "permission_denied"; |
    };
    r = 4;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... seems right.

Are you running this on a simulator?

If so, don't run Firebase Apps on a simulator. I don't know what but when I'm on a simulator, Firebase queries don't work 20-30% of the time. I've never had a problem on a phone. I've done a lot of projects with Firebase and every time I'm on a simulator, the database just stops working at least once a day for pockets of time.

Hope that helps.

I personally use:

```
ref.observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: { snapshot in
        print(snapshot)
})
```

which you already have listed.

Comment: I am not using the simulator. Been running it on the phone the entire time